# How do I change xcode code sign identity and application name?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an ios application that runs on xcode 3.2.6. I want to change application name and application icon. I also want to use another developer identity. In xcode 3  I did not find  how to change this and now I am moving to xcode 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the application icon go to Application Targets -> info - > and in the Icon file column write the name of the image with its extension example: abc.png and put the image in the project.
And for the development identity select project and select Build Setting and choose Code Signing column and set the appropriate profile.